# Assistance needed for scripting the MatLab rot90 function

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

This is supposed to rotate a matrix 90 degrees like the function rot90. It doesn't work correctly any help is much appreciated.

```
%// This script will perform the same operation as rot90
clc
clear all

mat = input('Enter the matrix: ');
drctn = input('Which direction to rotate the matrix\nEnter -90 0r 90: ');
[m,n] = size(mat);
rows = 0;
cols = 0;

for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
       if drctn == -90 %// Rotate counter clockwise
          mat(i) = mat(j);
       elseif drctn == 90  %// Rotate clockwise
          mat(j)= mat(i);
       end
    end
end
mat
```

Comment: You are overwriting elements of the matrix then accessing them again later. Don't modify the original matrix, create a new rotated one.

Answer (score 1):

David basically nailed it on the head.  You are overwriting values in your matrix as you are rotating them.  Create a **new** matrix that stores the rotated elements.

However, I would personally do away with the loop.  If you want to rotate the matrix 90 degrees counter-clockwise, you can see that you simply reverse the direction of each row so that they're read out in reverse order, then take the transpose... so something like this:

```
out = fliplr(mat).';
```

If you want to rotate clockwise, you go in the opposite order.  You transpose first, then reverse the order of each row:

```
out = fliplr(mat.');
```

We can double check this by using `rot90` from MATLAB.  Given this sample matrix:

```
>> A = reshape(1:16,4,4)

A =

     1     5     9    13
     2     6    10    14
     3     7    11    15
     4     8    12    16
```

Let's take a look at `rot90` going counter-clockwise:

```
>> B = rot90(A)

B =

    13    14    15    16
     9    10    11    12
     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4

>> B2 = fliplr(A).'

B2 =

    13    14    15    16
     9    10    11    12
     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4
```

If you want to go clockwise, it's the same as using `rot90` but going in the reverse direction:

```
>> B = rot90(A, -1)

B =

     4     3     2     1
     8     7     6     5
    12    11    10     9
    16    15    14    13

>> B2 = fliplr(A.')

B2 =

     4     3     2     1
     8     7     6     5
    12    11    10     9
    16    15    14    13
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to achieve the desired results by manipulating the matrix elements. This is how I did it.                                                                clc
clear all
mat = input('Enter the matrix: ');
drctn = input('Which direction to rotate the matrix\nEnter l or r: ','s');
[m,n] = size(mat);
fprintf('You entered\n')
disp(mat)
for i = 1:m
        if drctn == 90  %Rotate clockwise
            mat90(:,i) = mat(m-i+1,:);
        elseif drctn == -90  %Rotate counter clockwise
            mat90(i,:)= mat(:,m-i+1);
        end
end
fprintf('The result is\n')
disp(mat90)

Comment: So was I able to answer your question or not?

Comment: Yes you answered the question with a useful solution but I needed to manipulate the matrix without using built in functions.

Comment: @user3749150 - That wasn't very clear in your question.  Besides which, you can replace `fliplr` with the appropriate matrix slicing operations.  Either way, consider adding in your own answer to let the StackOverflow community know that you no longer need help.  Take care.